# How to create Admin-User for (Role) specific category-only access in magento2, It Possible or Not?

Tags: magento2, category, multistore, user-roles, admin-user

I have Created two-stores,

And I have Add two Root-Category ,

But I Need to Create Two AdminUser for  make(Role to) access for specific one-Store Category.

Example

(AdminUser A)-> Specific access only Category A

(AdminUser B)-> Specific access only Category B

It's Possible or Not in magento2 application?

Comment: it's not possile in magento 2 application

Answer (score 0):

I think yes it is possible, to achieve the above functionality at login time you should identify the store. So to achieve this i think you need to modify the admin login form also. In admin login form you can ask them to enter store name or something so by considering these details you can show specific category.